# mysql query on 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This query not select, no comment or no vote data, how I fix ?

```
SELECT 
    blog_posts.*, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(blog_comments.CommentID))  AS CountComments, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(blog_votes.VoteID)) AS CountVotes,
    AVG(DISTINCT(blog_votes.Vote)) AS AvgVote 
    FROM blog_posts 
    INNER JOIN blog_comments ON blog_comments.CommentBlogID=blog_posts.BlogID 
    INNER JOIN blog_votes ON blog_votes.VoteBlogID=blog_posts.BlogID 
    ORDER BY blog_posts.BlogID
    LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: `GROUP BY blog_post.col1, blog_posts.col_2,...`

Comment: So you wanna count Comments, Votes and Average of Votes data ?

Comment: @MichaelAntonio its true

Comment: @lad2025 nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

I fixed

```
SELECT
blog_posts.*,
COUNT(VoteID) as CountVotes,
AVG(VoteID) As AvgVotes,
COUNT(CommentID) AS CountComments
FROM blog_posts
LEFT JOIN blog_votes ON blog_posts.BlogID = blog_votes.VoteBlogID
LEFT JOIN blog_comments ON blog_posts.BlogID = blog_comments.CommentBlogID
GROUP BY blog_posts.BlogID
ORDER BY BlogID DESC  
LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, I use subquery to make it simple :

```
SELECT  b.*,
  COUNT(select CommentID from blog_comments where CommentBlogID = b.BlogID group by CommentID) as CountComments,
  COUNT(select VoteID from blog_comments where VoteBlogID = b.BlogID group by VoteID) as CountVotes,
  AVG(select Vote from blog_comments where VoteBlogID = b.BlogID group by Vote) as AvgVote,
FROM blog_posts as b
ORDER BY b.BlogID
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT blog_comments.CommentID 
      FROM blog_comments 
      WHERE blog_com' at line 3